# SQL get counts of unique values

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, distinct

Using sqlite3, how can I get the different "count" columns for this example in-memory database?
Using version 3.27.2

**Example Database**

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id1, 
    id2, 
    id3, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
);

INSERT INTO events (id1, id2, id3)
VALUES 
   (1,1,99),
   (1,2,99),
   (1,3,52),
   (2,1,6),
   (2,2,7),
   (2,3,8)
;

.mode columns
.header on
SELECT * FROM events;
```

[image]

**Desired Printed Output**

[image]

**Partial Success**
The following works for the first two new columns.

```
SELECT id1, count(id3) AS total_count, count(DISTINCT id3) AS unique_count
FROM events
GROUP BY id1;
```

What is the best way to get the last column? The following returns `error: no such column: total_count`

```
SELECT id1, count(id3) AS total_count, count(DISTINCT id3) AS unique_count, (total_count - unique_count) AS repeated_count
FROM events
GROUP BY id1;
```

Comment: The total count minus the unique count doesn't get you the repeated count number. Please see my answer on this. (If you just wanted the `total_count - unique_count`, you could just use `count(*) - count(distinct id3)`. You cannot access aliases in the same clause where you define them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `group by id1, id3` like this:

```
SELECT id1, id3, COUNT(*) counter
FROM events
GROUP BY id1, id3;
```

you get the number of rows for each combination of `id1, id3`:

| id1 | id3 | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | 1 |
| 1 | 99 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 |

Now, all you have to do is:

- sum the column `counter` for each `id1` to get the column
  `total_count`
- count the number of rows for each `id1` to get the
  column `unique_count`
- count the number of rows for each `id1` where
  the column `counter` is `> 1` to get the column `repeated_id3`

You can do this with `SUM()` and `COUNT()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, 
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY id1) AS total_count, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id1) AS unique_count,
       SUM(COUNT(*) > 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id1) repeated_id3
FROM events
GROUP BY id1, id3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=655888e5f33c5e6c2c1f6d997d88328a).
Results:

| id1 | total_count | unique_count | repeated_id3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a CTE. Haven't validated the syntax but this seems to be a valid option from viewing the SQLlite documentation.

```
With X as 
(
SELECT id1, count(id3) AS total_count, count(DISTINCT id3) AS unique_count
FROM events
GROUP BY id1;
)
select id1, total_count, unique_count, (total_count - unique_count) AS repeated_count
from X
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not that easy :-)

In

```
(1,1,99), (1,2,99), (1,3,52)
```

there is one ID repeated (the 99).

In

```
(1,1,99), (1,2,99), (1,3,52), (1,4,99)
```

there is again one ID repeated (still the 99).

In

```
(1,1,99), (1,2,99), (1,3,52), (1,4,52)
```

there are two IDs repeated (the 52 and the 99).

When just aggregating by ID1, you lose that knowledge. You see how many rows there were and how many different ID3s, but not which of these ID3s had duplicates. This means you need an intermediate step, a pre-aggregation before the final aggregation.

```
select
  id1,
  count(*) as total_count,
  count(distinct id3) as unique_count,
  count(case when cnt > 1 then 1 end) as repeated_count
from
(
  select id1, id3, count(*) as cnt
  from events
  group by id1, id3
) pre_aggregated
group by id1
order by id1;
```